# Custom font file type

Tags: web, font-face

I want to install a custom font on a website, does anyone know if .ttf format is enough?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a custom font on your website, I recommend using one of Google web fonts. You will find more info [here](http://www.google.com/webfonts).

If the font you want to use is not on the list. I recommend using font-squirrel and create a font-face kit with their [generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

To work on a larger range of browsers, you should use .ttf, .eot, .svg and .woff.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

TTF will work for most modern browsers. Of course, you may offer several alternative font formats to the user agent - it surely won't hurt )

Here is the compatibility table for TrueType fonts: 
http://caniuse.com/ttf

In your CSS, declare the font as follows:

```
@font-face
{
  font-family: my_font; 
  src: url('my_font.ttf');
}
```

And then use the `font-family` property it as usual:

```
.my_selector 
{
  font-family: my_font; 
}
```